# macOS12.x, BLE kCBAdvDataLocalName is empty

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I startAdvertising, my localName is long, more than 8 bytes. like @"123456789".

```objectivec
   [_peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{
            CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: @"123456789",
            CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"bbbb14c7-4697-aaaa-b436-d47e3d4ed187"]]
            }];
```

When running on macOS 11.x though localName exceeds 8 bytes. But it can still be scanned.

```objectivec
{
  kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
  kCBAdvDataLocalName = 123456789;
  kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 0;
  kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
  kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =   (
    "BBBB14C7-4697-AAAA-B436-D47E3D4ED187"
  );
  kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "680712553.800874";
  kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 12;
}
```

But running after macOS 12.x, if localName exceeds 8 bytes, it will be completely ignored. In the scanned data, localName is empty.

```objectivec
{
  kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
  kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 0;
  kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
  kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =   (
    "BBBB14C7-4697-AAAA-B436-D47E3D4ED187"
  );
  kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "680712744.108894";
  kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 12;
}
```

On macOS11.x, **SCAN_RSP** is utilized if localName exceeds 8 bytes,

[image: macos11]

while on macOS12.x, **SCAN_RSP** is always empty.

[image: macos12]

1. Why are there differences between macOS11.x and macos12.x, is there any documentation?
2. What is the maximum limit for localName? (On macOS 11.x, I verified it was 29 bytes
3. Are there other ways to broadcast longer data?

Does anyone know why? This has bothered me for a long time...